# Returns a count of the number of words in the string that contain length characters

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am a few weeks into learning python properly and couldn't find a way to proceed from what I currently have. The question is:

> Write a function num_words(string, length) that takes a string argument and returns a count of the number of words in the string that contain length characters. If there are no words of the given length then 0 should be returned.
> A word is defined as a maximal-length sequence of characters other than "white space" characters.
> Hint: use the split method of a string.

I currently have:

```
def num_words(string, length):
    """Takes a string argument and returns a count of the 
    number of words in the string that contain length characters"""
    result = ()
    for strings in string:
        for letters in strings:
            len(letters.split(string))
            return letters
    
word_count = num_words("Oh no it's a list filter!", 2)
print(word_count)
word_count = num_words("Oh no its a list filter!", 4)
print(word_count)
```

The output is

```
0
0
```

What it should output:

```
2
1
```

Using these tests:

```
word_count = num_words("Oh no it's a list filter!", 2)
print(word_count)

word_count = num_words("Oh no its a list filter!", 4)
print(word_count)
```

I think you have to use a nested for loop with len and split function but don't know how to find the length of letters in a word and then return that with the corresponding length. A full answer will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you invoked the function:

```
num_words("Oh no it's a list filter!", 2)
```

So, the `string` parameter is `"Oh no it's a list filter!"`.

Then, in the body of the function:

```
...
for strings in string:
    for letters in strings:
        len(letters.split(string))
        return letters
```

The first for-loop (`for strings in string:`) iterates through every character of the `string` parameter. For each iteration of the loop, `strings` will be a single character. For example, during the first iteration, it will be `"O"`, during the second, it will be `"h"`.

The second, nested for-loop (`for letters in strings:`) iterates through all of the characters in `strings`. Since `strings` will always be a string with just one character, this inner loop also will only have one iteration, and is basically pointless.

The rest of the code doesn't really make sense. You compute the length of the list `letters.split(string)`, and immediately discard the result. You then return the string `letters`, which terminates your function prematurely, and also doesn't match the output you claim you have.

You'll want to split your `string` parameter on whitespace to get a list of words (strings), then filter the list of words to retain only the ones that have the required number of letters, then return the length of that list:

```
def num_words(string, required_length):
    tally = 0
    for word in string.split():
        if len(word) == required_length:
            tally += 1
    return tally
```

Or something like:

```
def num_words(string, required_length):
    return len(list(filter(lambda word: len(word)==required_length, string.split())))
```

Comment: Oh, the joys of duck typing! Note to OP: If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's probably a duck. Except when it's a string.

Comment: @penguins1234 You're welcome. Let me know if anything is confusing.

Comment: `sum(len(word) == length for word in string.split())`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the string into words, check the length of each, and have a variable that keeps track of the total count of words of the required length. Note that the final `return` statement should be outside of any loop (so that the loop completes fully before the count is returned). Note also that only one `for` loop is needed (the loop over words) -- you do not need to loop over characters because the `len` function will already tell you the number of characters in the word.

```
def num_words(string, length):
    """Takes a string argument and returns a count of the 
    number of words in the string that contain length characters"""
    count = 0
    for word in string.split():
        if len(word) == length:
            count += 1
    return count
    
word_count = num_words("Oh no it's a list filter!", 2)
print(word_count)
word_count = num_words("Oh no its a list filter!", 4)
print(word_count)
```